# Nonabelian group of order 100 every element has order at most 10

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to find an example of a nonabelain group of order 100 in which every element has order at most 10.

I have been trying to use dihedral groups (D_n = {e, f, f^2, ... , f^{n-1}, g, fg, f^{2}g, ..., f^{n-1}g} ) and have considered the dihedral group D_50. This would have 100 elements so it would have order 100 although I am not entirely sure how to show that each element has order of at most 10.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to prove this or any other suggestions of examples that would be extremely helpful!

Comment: $D_{50}$ (the symmetry group of the regular $50$-gon) has an element of order $50$, do that's no good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems $D_5 \times D_5$ should work.  $100$ elements, non-abelian. Each element in the base groups can have order $1,2,5,10$ so the order of an element in the product group, which is the least common multiple of the orders in the base groups, is at most $10$.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you!

Comment: I may be missing something but how do you know D_5 X D_5 has 100 elements?

Comment: $D_5$ has 10 elements, so ${D_5}^2$ has $10^2=100$ elements.

Answer (score 1):

$$\prod\limits_{i=1}^2D_{10}$$

Comment: Doesn't that have $400$ elements?   $D_n$ has $2n$ elements

Comment: $D_n$ is order $2n$ not order $n$.

Comment: There are different conventions for the dihedral groups. One convention makes the number of vertices of the polygon the index, the other the number of elements, @GabrielBurns. Here apparently the latter convention is used. (I prefer the former, but meh.)

Answer (score 1):

$D_{10}\times D_{10}$ is an example , another is $C_{10} \times D_{10}$

Moreover, two non-abelian groups with structure $(C_5\times C_5):C_4$ have no element with order larger then $5$.

Comment: You mean $D_{5}\times D_{5}$? (see Gabriel Burns answer)

Comment: GAP, for example, denotes $D_{10}$ to be the dihedral-group of order $10$. Otherwise, you can replace $D_{10}$ by $D_5$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that the 2 notations are coexisting.